# How do you use an enum with another enum?

Tags: java, selenium, enums, webdriver, command-line-arguments

I'm making a selenium webdriver and I have an enum for the environments I am testing my app in and an enum for the app itself. My problem is I can't figure out how to use the environment enum inside the app enum in order to open it. I have a comment at the two spots I think my problem is. I get an error at the first comment so whatever would go there would be helpful.

```
public enum ENV
            {
                QA, STAGE, 
                PROD, DEV;
                 public String toString()
                {
                    switch(this)
                    {
                    case QA: return "http://****/qa_was8.html";
                    case STAGE: return "http://****/stage.html";
                    case PROD: return "http://****/prod.html";
                    case DEV: return "http://****/index.html";
                    default: return "http://****/qa_was8.html";
                    }


                }
            }



            public enum Application
            {
                ACCOUNTINVENTORY , AUDITACTIONITEMS;


                public static Application chooseApp(String args)
                {

                       File file = new File("H:\\InternStuff\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
                        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath() ); 
                        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    for(Application app : Application.values()) 
                    {


                    switch(app)
                    {


                    case ACCOUNTINVENTORY:


                        driver.get(ENV.valueOf(args[1]));//What would go here
                        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Account Inventory")).click();
                        driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys("****");
                        driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys("****");
                        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit']")).click();
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        driver.findElement(By.className("inputText")).sendKeys("smith");
                        driver.findElement(By.className("commandExButton")).click();
                    break;  
                    case AUDITACTIONITEMS:


                        driver.findElement(By.linkText("AuditAction Items")).click();
                        driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys("****");
                        driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys("****");
                        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit']")).click();
                        try {
                            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        driver.findElement(By.className("commandExButton")).click();
                    default:
                        System.out.println("...");
                        }
                    }
                    return null;

                }
            }


public static void main(String[] args) 

{

    if(args.length != 0)
    {
        Application app = Application.chooseApp(args[1]);
        ENV env = ENV.valueOf(args[0]);
        if(app != null)
        {
            app.toString();
        }
        else if(env != null)
        {
            env.toString();// Or maybe is my problem here?
        }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: can you post the error?

Comment: at my first comment in the code there's a red line under the args[1] and it says "the type of expression must be an array type but it resolved to String".

Comment: Did you mean to have the parameter for chooseApp be String[] args?

Comment: @wckd that was the first problem but now I am getting an error under the get in driver.get(ENV.valueOf(args[1])); that says"the method get(String) in the type Webdriver is not applicable for the arguments (WebDriver2.ENV)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you have a compile time error because you are attempting to treat `String args` as a `String[]` in `chooseApp`. The easiest solution I see is to pass the entire `args` array to `chooseApp`,

```
public static Application chooseApp(String[] args)
  // ...
  driver.get(ENV.valueOf(args[1]));// <-- now you can access args[1]
```

then

```
Application app = Application.chooseApp(args);
```

Comment: This almost completely worked and thank you so much. But when I run it instead of trying to use the Environment enum to open the correct site it is using the app name for the url. So instead of opening http://****/qa_was8.html it is trying to open accountinventory. My arguments are in the correct order so I know it is not that.

Comment: @Zach Try `driver.get(ENV.valueOf(args[0]))` instead of `driver.get(ENV.valueOf(args[1]))`. If that doesn't solve it, post your arguments 'cause I'm just trying to guess from your code. Also, I suggest you try a debugger in future.

Comment: Thanks again but now there's an error line under get that says "the method get(String) in the type Webdriver is not applicable for the arguments (WebDriver2.ENV)